# Effective action for 1D anti-ferromagnet

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, effective-field-theory

I'm following Fradkin's (p. 204) derivation of the effective action for a 1D anti-ferromagnet. 
He splits the spin field $\vec{n}$ into two pieces - a slowly varying $\vec{m}(j)$ which is the order parameter, and the average spin $\vec{l}(j)$:
$$\vec{n}(j) = \vec{m}(j) + (-1)^ja_0\vec{l}(j)$$ 
By collecting similart terms in the Lagrangian he arrives at

$$\mathcal{L}_M=-2a_0JS^2\vec{l}^2+s\vec{l}\cdot(\vec{m}\times\partial_0\vec{m})-\frac{a_0JS^2}{2}(\partial_1 \vec{m})^2+\frac{S}{2}\vec{m}\cdot(\partial_0\vec{m}\times\partial_1\vec{m})$$ 
The he moves on to integrate out the average spin density:
$$\mathcal{L}_M=\frac{S}{4}(\frac{1}{2a_0JS}(\partial_0 \vec{m})^2-2a_0JS(\partial_1 \vec{m})^2)+\frac{S}{4}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}\vec{m}\cdot(\partial_mu\vec{m}\times\partial_\nu\vec{m})$$

My problem is to arrive from the first Lagrangian to the second. I thought it might be a Gaussian integral, or a saddle point approximation, but I specifically can't figure how to get a term proportional to $(\partial_0 \vec{m})^2$ (While the other two seem to be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the Gaussian integral:
$$\begin{split}
&-\frac{1}{2}\vec{l}^2+\vec{l}\cdot(\vec{m}\times\partial_0\vec{m})\\
\to&\frac{1}{2}(\vec{m}\times\partial_0\vec{m})^2\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\vec{m}^2(\partial_0\vec{m})^2-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{m}\cdot\partial_0\vec{m})^2\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\vec{m}^2(\partial_0\vec{m})^2-\frac{1}{8}(\partial_0\vec{m}^2)^2\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(\partial_0\vec{m})^2,
\end{split}$$
using the fact that $\vec{m}^2=1$ and hence $\partial_0\vec{m}^2=\partial_01=0$. I am slopy with all the prefactors for simplicity.